# Powershell scripts: Create user profile synchronization service using sharepoint active directory

Tags: powershell, user-profile-service, 2013, synchronisation

In sharepoint 2013 I have to create user profile synchronization connection using sharepoint active directory through scripts. I have created the user profile service using powershell after that is there any way to select the option in **Configure Synchronization Settings** to select **Use SharePoint Active Directory** in Synchronization Options. 
After that I have to create the synchronization connection using scripts.

I have scripts for sharepoint 2010 but I could't find scripts for sharepoint 2013. If anyone have tried this before please help me out

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use the Add-SPProfileSyncConnection cmdlet.  Here is the TechNet documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219677.aspx